# RESTful API with associations best practice

Tags: java, rest

We are implementing a RESTful API and we have POST request that looks like this `/v1/systems/{systemId}/subsystems` and the body looks like this
`{"id": 0, "systemId": 0, "name": "string"}`.
Is this a duplication of the variables? It is good practice to have it like this?

Comment: For me yes it is duplicate, why do you want to have `systemId` at both path variable as well body? Why can't you use one?

Comment: May be it is due to overriding body. please check your client side code may be there body is overriding.

Comment: The path variable is required for the GET method. The `systemId` from the body is present because in the DTO we have it and it is mapped to the Response/RequestBody as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI as a whole is an identifier for the resource not just the last part. Whether the URI itself follows some structural design or not is also dependent on your design decisions. On its own a URI like `.../systems/{systemId}/subsystems` does not necessarily state that it is part of a `systems` collection with a parent resource identified by the respective `systemId`. This only "evolves" if a client naturally explores URIs that in total span a tree where this relationship is build. Though, such relations are usually expressed with link relations like `up` to reference the parent resource and `item` for a specific item in a collection, `subsection` for a sub-part of a collection resource an so forth. See [Iana's link relation registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) whether there are link relations available that fits your need. If none of the available link-relations fit your needs you can either register new ones with Iana or make use of [Web linking relation extensions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.2) where you can define private relations in your own namespace.

In regards to  adding the `systemId` in the body when you utilize a URI structure where the `systemId` is already used in the path to identify the parent resource, that information is then clearly redundant. But whether you want to include it still in the payload is your design choice. There is nothing wrong to include it or leave it out.

Unfortunately the information on the `subsystems` resource is rather limited. The current payload given could potentially be reduced to the name itself as the `systemId` is given in the URI and the `id` of the subsystem resource may be auto-generated and not be defined by the client. As such, the payload would reduce to a single name. Here you could also avoid the creation of the subresource alltogether and model the name of the subsystem within the `system` entry itself by designing it as array of names. Here, instead of a sub-resource creation you could simply provide an update method for the system resource (via Patch) to add the name to that array. But again, it is your design. Whatever works for you is fine here.

As a rule of thumb whether to include such information in the payload or not  you can take the Web as example. I.e. if the ID should be part of the representation to present to the final user, put it in. If not, leave it out. Think of a product which you want to render on a page. Sometimes it may be helpful if the respective productId is present if you want to give the customer a unique way of addressing that particular product in case of reclamations or questions. As resource identifiers however shouldn't change if possible it might be more benefitial to expose a UUID as internal product identifier and carry the product identifier customers should use in an other field with it. A customer of us once had a merger and in that merger they basically joined products from two companies all with different identifiers in their databases. As a consequence they had to modify a lot of resource URIs eventhough the products (in their real form) didn't change at all. As such, certain customers where all of a sudden unable to access previously bookmarked product descriptions and so forth as no redirect were introduced unfortunately. This for sure is an extreme and rare situation, though it may occur, and if you'd used a design that supports such a change by design the impact on the whole system would have been notably less dramatic.

So, long story short, it depends on your design whether the `systemId` is redundant information or whether you want to add that information to the payload or not or even avoid the subresource alltogether and instead carry the name within a listing of the parent system itself. There is neither a right nor wrong answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one doesn't POST to create a resource to a URL that points to a single resource. Your URL looks more correct for a GET, PUT or DELETE.

Without knowing your exact requirements, one could do:

```
POST body {"systemId": 0, "name": "string"} to /v1/systems or /v1/subsystems
```

The response could contain the created subsystem along with the new id.